# No sound when attached to docking station

Tags: ubuntu, audio, laptop, alsa

I have been using Linux and Ubuntu only since the last two months on my (2006) Sony Vaio VGN A617S laptop which is going pretty well on Ubuntu 10.10. When installing Ubuntu audio did get installed alright, and the speakers on the laptop itself are working well even now with the right drivers (snd-hda-intel) for the Realtek ALC260 soundcard.

My problem is when laptop is docked to the A/V docking station (I have seen it referred as a port replicator as well - the model number is VGP-PRAV2), with its two external speakers. And these were not on when Ubuntu was being installed. What is interesting is the headphones jack on the laptop does work when the docking station does not.

I have been trying hard and have already tried quite a few things I saw to be related issues, like: a) adjustments to some IEC958 in alsamixer b) using a custom mod for the ALC260 card

All this is to no avail.

If someone could help me with this, that would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I was trying to output sound from USB (dock-station) this solved it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10/668329#668329

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issues in Windows, while using HP laptops and its docking stations. These kinds of issues can be solved by connecting the laptop to the dock before starting the OS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this does not seem to help me, as even on a cold boot  with the docking station on, the speakers are simply quiet

Comment: Try installing while docked, not simply reboot. If you are interested in giving it another shot with out reinstalling, try installing lshw. Reference this post [here] [1]: http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/22/how-to-find-hardware-devices-in-ubuntu-with-lshw/

Answer (score 1):

Try [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/). This tool allows you to redirect the output to your various devices, even down to the per-application level.